# How to pass values aspx file to class.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

We can pass a value From aspx to aspx file using session, querystring and so.on.But i want to pass a value from aspx to class.cs file .In class.cs file i want to get that value. how to get thet value. can any body help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: Using the `runat="server"` attribute in your aspx file? It is not really clear what you want to do...

Comment: for example: default.aspx.cs page. decimal Total=textbox1.text+textbox2.aspx. I want to pass Total value in to Class.cs file.

Comment: Create an object of Class and call whatever methods you want on it.

Comment: can i have a example please.

Comment: @Sweety - **Only if you post what you have tried first.**  Besides the example nunespascal would give would be way to generic to be any help.

Comment: This isn't a site to get people to write your code for you. You need to post what you've tried and why it didn't work for you if you want help solving a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in aspx.cs

```
 decimal Total=textbox1.Text+textbox2.Text
```

In class

```
class sample
{
 Public void Display(decimal total)
 {
 }
 }
```

passing total to class method,write this after the first statement in aspx.cs file

```
 new sample().Display(Total)
```

Comment: In aspx.cs, class1 total_diff=new class().Display(Total); Is it correct.

Comment: @Sweety If you're creating a new instance of the class, never storing it anywhere, and only using it for this one method call, it probably means that the method should be static.

Comment: @Kiran `class` is a reserved word; you cannot call a class `class`.

Comment: @Servy that was just example,i wanted to give

Comment: @Kiran1016 And based on the OP's reply, that wasn't clear to them.

Comment: how to use total value in different method in same class.